# Linear Algebra : How to know if something is a linear transformation in this format?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

First of all, I know that a function is a linear transformation if for all vectors $u$ and $v$ in $R^m$ and all scalars $r$ we have:

a) $T(u+v) = T(u) + T(v)$

b) $T(ru) = rT(u)$

But what if you're given in this format:

$T(x_1, x_2) = (3x_1 + x_2, -2x_1, 4x_2)$

$x_1$, and $x_2$ are variables I'm assuming, so how would I work this into the formulas above to see if this equation is a linear transformation?

What is my $u$ and $v$ here? And do I just choose some random scalar to test it out?

Sorry if this is a mega newb question, I'm new to algebra and I'm having difficulties wrapping my head around these concepts.

Answer (score 1):

You´re $u$ and $v$ are pairs like $u=(x_1,x_2)$ and the same for $v$. So you use the definition of a sum of order pair I mean like $(x_1,x_2)+(y_1,y_2)=(x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2)$

You choose any one so you called it just $\alpha$ that belongs to the corresponding field

Answer (score 0):

Prove the following:

1. $T(x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2) = T(x_1,x_2) + T(y_1,y_2)$.
2. $T(\alpha x_1, \alpha x_2) = \alpha T(x_1,x_2)$.